# Java program not running while it should

Tags: java, eclipse

For a project in school we got a simple simulator for a parking lot, and it is our job to add features to this simulator. I'm trying to add a GUI to the simulator and so that you can fill in your values and that the simulation bases its simulation based upon those values. But i first made a simple button to go from 1 frame to the other but when i run the Frame1 file with the following code:

```
JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.dispose();
                 Simulator mysimulator = new Simulator();
                mysimulator.run();
                }
```

it doesn't load, it just gives me a blank window.

the view of the simulator is made in the following code:

```
    //package Parkeersimulator;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SimulatorView extends JFrame {
    public JFrame frame;
    private CarParkView carParkView;
    private int numberOfFloors;
    private int numberOfRows;
    private int numberOfPlaces;
    private int numberOfOpenSpots;
    private Car[][][] cars;

    public SimulatorView(int numberOfFloors, int numberOfRows, int numberOfPlaces) {
        this.numberOfFloors = numberOfFloors;
        this.numberOfRows = numberOfRows;
        this.numberOfPlaces = numberOfPlaces;
        this.numberOfOpenSpots =numberOfFloors*numberOfRows*numberOfPlaces;
        cars = new Car[numberOfFloors][numberOfRows][numberOfPlaces];

        carParkView = new CarParkView();



        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(carParkView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);



        updateView();

                }

    public void updateView() {
        carParkView.updateView();
    }

    public int getNumberOfFloors() {
        return numberOfFloors;
    }

    public int getNumberOfRows() {
        return numberOfRows;
    }

    public int getNumberOfPlaces() {
        return numberOfPlaces;
    }

    public int getNumberOfOpenSpots(){
        return numberOfOpenSpots;
    }

    public Car getCarAt(Location location) {
        if (!locationIsValid(location)) {
            return null;
        }
        return cars[location.getFloor()][location.getRow()][location.getPlace()];
    }

    public boolean setCarAt(Location location, Car car) {
        if (!locationIsValid(location)) {
            return false;
        }
        Car oldCar = getCarAt(location);
        if (oldCar == null) {
            cars[location.getFloor()][location.getRow()][location.getPlace()] = car;
            car.setLocation(location);
            numberOfOpenSpots--;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Car removeCarAt(Location location) {
        if (!locationIsValid(location)) {
            return null;
        }
        Car car = getCarAt(location);
        if (car == null) {
            return null;
        }
        cars[location.getFloor()][location.getRow()][location.getPlace()] = null;
        car.setLocation(null);
        numberOfOpenSpots++;
        return car;
    }

    public Location getFirstFreeLocation() {
        for (int floor = 0; floor < getNumberOfFloors(); floor++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
                for (int place = 0; place < getNumberOfPlaces(); place++) {
                    Location location = new Location(floor, row, place);
                    if (getCarAt(location) == null) {
                        return location;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Car getFirstLeavingCar() {
        for (int floor = 0; floor < getNumberOfFloors(); floor++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
                for (int place = 0; place < getNumberOfPlaces(); place++) {
                    Location location = new Location(floor, row, place);
                    Car car = getCarAt(location);
                    if (car != null && car.getMinutesLeft() <= 0 && !car.getIsPaying()) {
                        return car;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void tick() {
        for (int floor = 0; floor < getNumberOfFloors(); floor++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
                for (int place = 0; place < getNumberOfPlaces(); place++) {
                    Location location = new Location(floor, row, place);
                    Car car = getCarAt(location);
                    if (car != null) {
                        car.tick();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean locationIsValid(Location location) {
        int floor = location.getFloor();
        int row = location.getRow();
        int place = location.getPlace();
        if (floor < 0 || floor >= numberOfFloors || row < 0 || row > numberOfRows || place < 0 || place > numberOfPlaces) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private class CarParkView extends JPanel {

        private Dimension size;
        private Image carParkImage;    

        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class CarPark
         */
        public CarParkView() {
            size = new Dimension(0, 0);
        }

        /**
         * Overridden. Tell the GUI manager how big we would like to be.
         */
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 500);
        }

        /**
         * Overriden. The car park view component needs to be redisplayed. Copy the
         * internal image to screen.
         */
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if (carParkImage == null) {
                return;
            }

            Dimension currentSize = getSize();
            if (size.equals(currentSize)) {
                g.drawImage(carParkImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
            else {
                // Rescale the previous image.
                g.drawImage(carParkImage, 0, 0, currentSize.width, currentSize.height, null);
            }
        }

        public void updateView() {
            // Create a new car park image if the size has changed.
            if (!size.equals(getSize())) {
                size = getSize();
                carParkImage = createImage(size.width, size.height);
            }
            Graphics graphics = carParkImage.getGraphics();
            for(int floor = 0; floor < getNumberOfFloors(); floor++) {
                for(int row = 0; row < getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
                    for(int place = 0; place < getNumberOfPlaces(); place++) {
                        Location location = new Location(floor, row, place);
                        Car car = getCarAt(location);
                        Color color = car == null ? Color.white : car.getColor();
                        drawPlace(graphics, location, color);
                    }
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }

        /**
         * Paint a place on this car park view in a given color.
         */
        private void drawPlace(Graphics graphics, Location location, Color color) {
            graphics.setColor(color);
            graphics.fillRect(
                    location.getFloor() * 260 + (1 + (int)Math.floor(location.getRow() * 0.5)) * 75 + (location.getRow() % 2) * 20,
                    60 + location.getPlace() * 10,
                    20 - 1,
                    10 - 1); // TODO use dynamic size or constants
        }
    }

}
```

and the simultion self is made in the following code:

```
    //package Parkeersimulator;

import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Simulator {

    private static final String AD_HOC = "1";
    private static final String PASS = "2";


    private CarQueue entranceCarQueue;
    private CarQueue entrancePassQueue;
    private CarQueue paymentCarQueue;
    private CarQueue exitCarQueue;
    private SimulatorView simulatorView;

    private int day = 0;
    private int hour = 0;
    private int minute = 0;

    private int tickPause = 100;

    int weekDayArrivals= 100; // average number of arriving cars per hour
    int weekendArrivals = 200; // average number of arriving cars per hour
    int weekDayPassArrivals= 50; // average number of arriving cars per hour
    int weekendPassArrivals = 5; // average number of arriving cars per hour

    int enterSpeed = 3; // number of cars that can enter per minute
    int paymentSpeed = 7; // number of cars that can pay per minute
    int exitSpeed = 5; // number of cars that can leave per minute


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Simulator mySimulator = new  Simulator();
        mySimulator.run();
            }


    public Simulator() {
        entranceCarQueue = new CarQueue();
        entrancePassQueue = new CarQueue();
        paymentCarQueue = new CarQueue();
        exitCarQueue = new CarQueue();
        simulatorView = new SimulatorView(3, 6, 30);
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            tick();
        }
    }

    private void tick() {
        advanceTime();
        handleExit();
        updateViews();
        // Pause.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(tickPause);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        handleEntrance();
    }

    private void advanceTime(){
        // Advance the time by one minute.
        minute++;
        while (minute > 59) {
            minute -= 60;
            hour++;
        }
        while (hour > 23) {
            hour -= 24;
            day++;
        }
        while (day > 6) {
            day -= 7;
        }

    }

    private void handleEntrance(){
        carsArriving();
        carsEntering(entrancePassQueue);
        carsEntering(entranceCarQueue);     
    }

    private void handleExit(){
        carsReadyToLeave();
        carsPaying();
        carsLeaving();
    }

    private void updateViews(){
        simulatorView.tick();
        // Update the car park view.
        simulatorView.updateView(); 
    }

    private void carsArriving(){
        int numberOfCars=getNumberOfCars(weekDayArrivals, weekendArrivals);
        addArrivingCars(numberOfCars, AD_HOC);      
        numberOfCars=getNumberOfCars(weekDayPassArrivals, weekendPassArrivals);
        addArrivingCars(numberOfCars, PASS);        
    }

    private void carsEntering(CarQueue queue){
        int i=0;
        // Remove car from the front of the queue and assign to a parking space.
        while (queue.carsInQueue()>0 && 
                simulatorView.getNumberOfOpenSpots()>0 && 
                i<enterSpeed) {
            Car car = queue.removeCar();
            Location freeLocation = simulatorView.getFirstFreeLocation();
            simulatorView.setCarAt(freeLocation, car);
            i++;
        }
    }

    private void carsReadyToLeave(){
        // Add leaving cars to the payment queue.
        Car car = simulatorView.getFirstLeavingCar();
        while (car!=null) {
            if (car.getHasToPay()){
                car.setIsPaying(true);
                paymentCarQueue.addCar(car);
            }
            else {
                carLeavesSpot(car);
            }
            car = simulatorView.getFirstLeavingCar();
        }
    }

    private void carsPaying(){
        // Let cars pay.
        int i=0;
        while (paymentCarQueue.carsInQueue()>0 && i < paymentSpeed){
            Car car = paymentCarQueue.removeCar();
            // TODO Handle payment.
            carLeavesSpot(car);
            i++;
        }
    }

    private void carsLeaving(){
        // Let cars leave.
        int i=0;
        while (exitCarQueue.carsInQueue()>0 && i < exitSpeed){
            exitCarQueue.removeCar();
            i++;
        }   
    }

    private int getNumberOfCars(int weekDay, int weekend){
        Random random = new Random();

        // Get the average number of cars that arrive per hour.
        int averageNumberOfCarsPerHour = day < 5
                ? weekDay
                : weekend;

        // Calculate the number of cars that arrive this minute.
        double standardDeviation = averageNumberOfCarsPerHour * 0.3;
        double numberOfCarsPerHour = averageNumberOfCarsPerHour + random.nextGaussian() * standardDeviation;
        return (int)Math.round(numberOfCarsPerHour / 60);   
    }

    private void addArrivingCars(int numberOfCars, String type){
        // Add the cars to the back of the queue.
        switch(type) {
        case AD_HOC: 
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCars; i++) {
                entranceCarQueue.addCar(new AdHocCar());
            }
            break;
        case PASS:
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCars; i++) {
                entrancePassQueue.addCar(new ParkingPassCar());
            }
            break;              
        }
    }

    private void carLeavesSpot(Car car){
        simulatorView.removeCarAt(car.getLocation());
        exitCarQueue.addCar(car);
    }

}
```

please do note that i only just began programming and i have little to no knowledge at all.

Comment: Just a note, when you override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` , start calling `super.paintComponent(g);` inside the overriden method .

Answer (score 0):

You need a add the button to a panel.

```
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
 Container content = this.getContentPane(); // Get the content pane
 content.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 content.add(btnSubmit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 setVisible(true); // Display the window
```

Comment: to what do i add the panel?

Comment: Change it a litlle bit 

         JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.dispose();
                 Simulator mysimulator = new Simulator();
                mysimulator.run();
                }};
         carParkView = new CarParkView();  // JPanel

        this.getContentPane().add(carParkView, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().add(btnSubmit, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);